# Is there any way write the test cases of Mouse & Keyboard events in Jest?

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, stenciljs

I am writing the Unit Test cases in JEST for Stencil-Js project. There are several mouse & keyboard event in my component, as follows.

- Click on button to open the Dropdown List
- With Specbar Key, open the Dropdown List
- With up/Down arrow keys, navigate the list
- On click/Enter select the value of Dropdown List item

I don't know about the, can we write the test case of events or not.

Please guide.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil/issues/572

There you can see how a KeyboardEvent is succesfully dispatched, with a code like this:

```js
const body = window.document.body;
body.dispatchEvent(new(window.window as any).KeyboardEvent('keyup', {
  keyCode: 27,
  bubbles: true,
  cancelable: true
}));
```

You can pick your own element to dispatch it